# Difference between 12.04 and 12.04.1 and boot problems

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 two days ago.  Or at least I thought it was 12.04, but actually 12.04.1.  Now I'm having errors popping up from the grub loader. `Error: no video mode activated` which was apparently resolved in this [bug# 699802](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/699802).  However these workarounds are for 11.xx and not working for me.  I never had these errors before with 12.04 and now I'm getting them.  What's the difference between 12.04 and 12.04.1?

Off the bat I notice that the kernels are different

12.04   uses 3.2.0-26-generic-pae

12.04.1 uses 3.2.0-29-generic

after an immediate `sudo apt-get update upgrade`

12.04.1 uses 3.2.0-30-generic

I have two other computers running 12.04 (not 12.04.1) and they're working fine.  The computer that I'm currently was working fine (with 12.04) previously too.

Should I roll back my kernel to 3.2.0-26?

Comment: I downvoted this question because it really is two questions in one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04.1 is just Ubuntu 12.04 but with all upgrades and fixed that have appeared between the official release and the time the new version popped out, all applied to it. So you can get to 12.04.1 in 2 ways (Same applies to any new version like 12.04.2, 12.04.3 and so on):

1. Download the updated 12.04 (12.04.1) from the Ubuntu website and install it (Will be mentioned as the latest version)
2. Install the 12.04 that was released on April and do a massive upgrade from that version till today. That should get you to 12.04.1 or any other newer version.

In relation with your problem, you will need to include more information (Recommend another question for it that does not mix with this one since you are asking the difference between 12.04.1 and 12.04). Information like hardware type, dmesg output and most of the /var/log files that give any indications of a problem.

Comment: iirc. 12.4 does not let you upgrade from 10.4 and 12.4.1 does so there is a bit of difference between the 2.

Comment: @Rinzwind - Don't understand the 10.04 in your comment.

Comment: @Rinzwind - Thanks but my question is, why would you bring it here since it is only for 12.04.x?

Comment: Because "Ubuntu 12.04.1 is just Ubuntu 12.04 but with all upgrades and fixed that have appeared between the official release and the time the new version popped out" is not entirely true ;)

Comment: What you talking about boss?. Am on chat if you want to continue the discussion. Bring it on!!